# JSONParser.parse() error

Tags: json, parsing, json-simple

I have been getting a error parse my JSON file

### Input

{"continent":"South America","recentJobRank":717,"latitude":"-34.6037232","lastSeenDate":"2012-11-23","start":"Inmediato","contactPerson":"Alejandra Perez","lastJobRank":2,"title":"Encimador","salary":"Convenio","jobtype":"Tiempo Completo","url":"http://www.computrabajo.com.ar/bt-ofrd-deglay-7148.htm","postedDate":"2012-11-21","duration":"Indeterminada","firstSeenDate":"2012-11-23","phoneNumber":"011 4648-0226 RRHH","faxNumber":"011 4648-0226","location":"Buenos Aires, Argentina","company":"Deglay S.R.L.","id":"34076","department":"Buenos Aires","category":"others","applications":"Por e-mail o comunicandose a los telefonos","longitude":"-58.3815931"}

Below is the exception i have recieved

### Exception

Unexpected character (J) at position 457.
Exception Caught in addfields
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)

I have tried checking my json on a Validator.It seems fine.
Any obvious mistake that i am making ?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is definitely correct, since JSON.parse() accepts it.
I can't really reproduce your error with the json-simple library. I downloaded every version available [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list), copy-pasted your JSON string and passed it to **JSONParser.parse()** and got no error in any version.

Here is my setup:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
      StringReader x = new StringReader("{\"continent\":\"South America\",\"recentJobRank\":717,\"latitude\":\"-34.6037232\",\"lastSeenDate\":\"2012-11-23\",\"start\":\"Inmediato\",\"contactPerson\":\"Alejandra Perez\",\"lastJobRank\":2,\"title\":\"Encimador\",\"salary\":\"Convenio\",\"jobtype\":\"Tiempo Completo\",\"url\":\"http://www.computrabajo.com.ar/bt-ofrd-deglay-7148.htm\",\"postedDate\":\"2012-11-21\",\"duration\":\"Indeterminada\",\"firstSeenDate\":\"2012-11-23\",\"phoneNumber\":\"011 4648-0226 RRHH\",\"faxNumber\":\"011 4648-0226\",\"location\":\"Buenos Aires, Argentina\",\"company\":\"Deglay S.R.L.\",\"id\":\"34076\",\"department\":\"Buenos Aires\",\"category\":\"others\",\"applications\":\"Por e-mail o comunicandose a los telefonos\",\"longitude\":\"-58.3815931\"}");
      new JSONParser().parse(x);
    } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }

    System.out.println("Success");    
}
```

So I assume neither your JSON, nor the library is at fault here. My guess would be the encoding of your JSON string, since the error message says

> Unexpected character (J) at position 457.

and there is no **J** anywhere close to this position. So either the JSON you receive is encoded in a way, which SimpleJSON can't correctly parse, or the data doesn't get transmitted completely/correctly.

Maybe it could help to tell, where you got the JSON from and how you pass it into JSONParser.parse().